# failurePolicy: true not retrying after failure

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Using Firebase RealTime Database, I recently analyzed unprocessed data that should have been handled by an onCreate background trigger function (V1).
In these cases, the event successfully triggered the function but due to some process, an error was thrown (which is fine, we handled it with failurePolicy: true)

But it appears the function was never retried.

So I wrote a test code to understand the problem and it never retries.
"Retry on failure" is active.

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
exports.test = functions.runWith({
    failurePolicy: true
  }).database.ref('/foo/bar/{UID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    functions.logger.log("START");
    throw new Error('Retrying...');
  });
```

here are the logs:

```
Function execution started
START
Function execution took 146 ms, finished with status: 'error'
Error: Retrying... at exports.handler ...
```